# How to add elements after fetching from RoomDb

Tags: java, android, android-room

I have prices of items stored in RoomDb.I want to fetch those prices and sum up in my app but I am unable to do it. This is what I have done so far. I am not able to retrieve the prices and sum them up.

Below is an error:

```
Process: com.app.genova, PID: 22586
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
    at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:132)
    at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:295)
    at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:285)
    at com.app.genova.CartFragment$1.onChanged(CartFragment.java:79)
    at com.app.genova.CartFragment$1.onChanged(CartFragment.java:76)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:131)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:149)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:307)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$1.run(LiveData.java:91)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7081)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:928)
```

Its showing error in given lines 76 and 79 respectively.

```
 s.observe(getActivity(), new Observer<Integer>() {
```

and

```
 Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Total "+String .valueOf(integer),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**CartProduct.java**

```
@Entity(tableName = "MyProduct")
public class CartProduct {

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
@NonNull
int id;

@ColumnInfo(name="_pid")
String _pid;

@ColumnInfo(name="name")
String name;

@ColumnInfo(name="price")
int price;
}
```

**ProductDao.java**

```
@Query("SELECT SUM(price) FROM MyProduct")
LiveData<Integer> getPriceSum();

@Query("SELECT * FROM MyProduct")
List<CartProduct> getAllProducts();
```

**CartFragment.java**

```
private void loadCart(){

     ProductDb  db = ProductDb.getInstance(getActivity());
    LiveData<Integer> s = db.productDao().getPriceSum();

    s.observe(getActivity(), new Observer<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(Integer integer) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Total "+String .valueOf(integer),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
 }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `cartList` a `LiveData`?

Comment: No I have not used livedata

Comment: So, you have to call `db.productDao().getAllProducts();` in a background thread .. Had you do this in the Database class?.. can you share it

Comment: I want to know how do I loop through price and add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would change the `price` to integer, you can do the sum with `Room` itself using SQLite `SUM` function

```
@Query("SELECT SUM(price) FROM MyProduct")
int getPriceSum();
```

And you can do it with `LiveData` to have instant trigger for any change in the price

```
@Query("SELECT SUM(price) FROM MyProduct")
LiveData<Integer> getPriceSum();
```

Dealing with numbers is more efficient than Strings and will make you avoid potential errors when it comes to mathematical operations.

**UPDATE:**

`LiveData` implicitly works in background thread, so when you access it in the UI thread, it returns null until it takes a value

Instead of that:

`LiveData` follows the [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), which means that it can be observed by the current Life Cycle Owner (i.e. activity/fragment).

this can be achieved by: `myLiveData.observe(myLifeCycleOwner, new Observer(...)`

To apply that on your snippet:

```
ProductDb  db = ProductDb.getInstance(context);         
LiveData<Integer> s = db.productDao().getPriceSum();

s.observe(this, new Observer<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(Integer integer) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onChanged: " + integer);
        Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(integer) ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thought of the same but the type of the `price` is `string`

Comment: I am trying to get sum like this `ProductDb  db = ProductDb.getInstance(context);
        LiveData<Integer> s = db.productDao().getPriceSum();

        Toast.makeText(context,s.getValue(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`.But its showing error `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference`.

Comment: @Digvijay  `LiveData` works in background thread, so when you access it in the UI thread it returns null , please check updated answer

Comment: I have changes my implementation as u did  now app is  not crashing but price sum is showing 0 though I have items in database.

Comment: @Digvijay I have tested this code and working .. probably all products` prices are 0 .. can you add a brand-new product with a price value and test

Comment: I have added fresh new product but still showing 0.I updated my post with latest code please take a look.

Comment: I am taking price as a string value in db do I need to convert it into Integer first  is that the reason its showing total price 0.

Comment: You select `image_url` not `price` in `@Query("SELECT SUM(image_url) FROM MyProduct")` .. also you need to change the `price` type in `CartProduct.java` to be `int`

Comment: I am getting this error `ava.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference` on doing ` s.observe(getActivity(), new Observer<Integer>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(Integer integer) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Total "+String .valueOf(integer),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });`

Comment: @Digvijay This error related to null context .. Can you replace the `getActivity()` with `this` to refer to the fragment itself.. also if possible to provide the full Fragment code even in `pastebin.com`

Comment: @Zain Issue resolved,Thanks for your time.

Comment: happy to hear that .. any time :)

Answer (score 1):

To sum up the prices you can try the following

```
  int priceSum = 0;
  cartList = db.productDao().getAllProducts();
  for(CartProduct cartProduct : cartList){
      priceSum+=Integer.parseInt(cartProduct.getPrice())
  }
  //add the corresponding getters in the Entity-class
```

Edit:

If your requirements just depend on the `priceSum` then you can avoid fetching the whole list by following @Zain approach by changing the data type of `price` to `int`.